# Travis ci fails with mocha+coveralls

Tags: mocha.js, travis-ci, coveralls

travis ci fails as the out put of reporter is empty string.

```
NODE_ENV=test YOURPACKAGE_COVERAGE=1 mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register --require blanket --reporter mocha-lcov-reporter | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js
```

It works fine in my local.

```
> mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register --require blanket --reporter mocha-lcov-reporter | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js
[error] "2015-04-26T12:41:57.904Z"  'error from lcovParse: ' 'Failed to parse string'
[error] "2015-04-26T12:41:57.906Z"  'input: ' ''
[error] "2015-04-26T12:41:57.906Z"  'error from convertLcovToCoveralls'
```

Comment: What do you have in your .travis.yml?

Comment: I've faced a similar problem, hope [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362121/how-to-configure-coveralls-with-github-action/65615948#65615948) might help you a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Travis CI to install the latest node before execution:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because some tools is working only with latest version of node. I had the sample problem until i change version of node in my `.travis.yaml`:

```
node_js:
- "6"
```