# How to configure Coveralls with Github Action?

Tags: continuous-integration, code-coverage, github-actions, coveralls

I'm experiencing problems with my github repo configuration. Here it is - [umbress](https://github.com/JamesJGoodwin/umbress). I have Github Actions CI enabled and configured and I want to have the coverage badge in my repo so everyone who wants to use my code in their projects knows that my code is well-tested. But it seems that I missing something because my coverage badge has an "unknown" status for a long time already.

CI steps are:

1. Run build
2. Run tests and generate coverage (`jest --coverage --config config/jest.js`). This will generate `./coverage/lcov.info` in root directory
3. Finally [Coveralls GitHub Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/coveralls-github-action) should upload coverage to their website and display the results

There are a few issues:

1. When I run builds on pull requests, it says "First build" (but it's not, I've ran a lot of builds on this branch already)
   [image: github actions]
2. Coverage info is differs in what jest shows me after tests and what is displaying in Coveralls stats (i.e. in Coveralls it says `FIRST BUILD ON DEVELOPER AT 90.072%`, but there's no such percentage at all! Lines covered is `93.43%` and everything in average is `89.4%`)
3. Coverage badge is "unknown" no matter I try to change

What am I doing wrong and what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 12):

I've tried many things as well and in the end, the usage of the [coverallsapp/github-action@v1.1.2](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/coveralls-github-action#standard-example) helped! Now I can successfully publish the coverage results to coveralls.io

Unfortunately, the straightforward approach was either leading to "Bad Response 422 - Couldn't find a repository matching this job" or "Error from lcovParse: 'Failed to parse string'".

Straightforward approach **(not working):**

```
- name: Publish to coveralls.io
  run: cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js
```

Using Actions app from GH marketplace **(working):**

```
- name: Publish to coveralls.io
  uses: coverallsapp/github-action@v1.1.2
  with:
    github-token: ${{ github.token }}
```

**This is the [working .yml configuration](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular/blob/c91c019dfa3fa367137a4e06b92ee2f043a94e27/.github/workflows/nodejs.yml), hope it will help someone else as well.**

Keep in mind that the scenario that I needed to cover was a little bit tricky, we have multiple coverage results that needed to be combined and later on used as a single output result to coveralls.io.

If someone is curious, here are the things that I've tried, but failed:

- Use of NODE_ENV for publishing -

  run: **NODE_ENV=test** cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js
- Specifying exact node version [11.8.0 and above](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/973)
- Specifying a **github.token, repo and env** for the steps:
- Creating a separate **Github Actions Job**.

  ```
  uses: actions/setup-node@v1
  with:
    repo-token: ${{ github.token }}
    repository: ${{ github.repository }}
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
  ```

Comment: Both the [coveralls documentation](https://docs.coveralls.io/) and even the [npm coveralls package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coveralls#github-actions-ci) recommend using the Coveralls GitHub Action (as you suggested in your answer). So I guess that's the way to go!